# HttpURLConnection, How is the content of a response decoded?

Tags: android, character-encoding, httpurlconnection

On an Android device, could an `HttpURLConnection` recognize the `charset` of its response automatically?

That is, if I have received some plain text response through an `HttpURLConnection`, can I get a right `String` (or maybe a right Reader) without knowing the `charset` used to encode the response?

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getContentType()` which returns the responses MIME type. If it's a text-based response then this may include the character set, which you can then extract and pass to an `InputStreamReader` along with the `InputStream` you get by calling `getInputStream()`.

If the response is not text-based, i.e. it's binary data, then the concept of charset is meaningless.

Comment: So there is no automatic way?

Comment: What do you mean "automatic"? I have told you exactly how to read the charset if it is available.

Comment: "automatic" I mean "... without knowing the charset used ...". Actually I know I can parse Content-Type myself... but it just doesn't feel quite nice...